# Problema con fechas en php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo php:

```
<?php foreach($rst_vis as $registro): ?>

<tr>
<td><h6><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></h6></td>


<td>
<h6><?php echo $registro->placa ?></h6>

</td>
<td>
<h6><?php echo $registro->fecha1 ?></h6>
</td>
<td>
<h6><?php echo $registro->fecha2 ?></h6>
</td>
<td>
<h6><?php 
if($registro->accion>1){

  $entrada = new DateTime($registro->fecha1);     //campo DateTime de mysql

  $salida = new DateTime($registro->fecha2);      //campo DateTime de mysql

  $diferencia = $entrada->diff($salida);

  $horas=0; $minutos=0; $cadena="";

  if(($diferencia->d)>0){
    $horas = ($diferencia->d) * 24;
  }


  $horas = $diferencia->h; //horas
  $minutos = $diferencia->i; //minutos

  if($horas>0){
    $cadena = $horas . " h ";
  }
  if($minutos>0){
    $cadena = $cadena .  $minutos . " m";
    }

  echo $cadena;
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Es un control de entrada. En mysql guardo en un campo `DateTime`, la fecha-hora de entrada y salida, luego saco el intervalo de tiempo para mostrarlo. 
El problema es que me funciona localmente en mi equipo, pero al subirlo al servidor, no funciona. Se detiene el código en la primera linea. No se si hay mal en esa declaración. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error, te dice algo o como sabes que se detiene en esa linea?

Comment: ¿Qué es `$registro`? ¿Quizá falte algún archivo que estás usando en local que en el servidor no exista?

Comment: Porque todo ese codigo lo tengo entra <td></td> para mostrarlo en una tabla. Hice prueba poniendo una instruccion 'echo"*"', para ver donde se detenia y encontre que el asterico me aparece en la celda, cuando lo prongo antes d ela primera instruccion, ya despues, no me aparece.

Comment: $registro->entrada y $registro->salida, son campos mysql

Comment: Pero a lo que se refieren cuando te preguntan que es `$registro` es donde se define pues lo que compartes no se ve de donde sale.

Comment: Todo el codigo esta en un bucle que lee los registros mysql:  <?php foreach($rst_vis as $registro): ?>

Comment: Seguramente la respuesta que buscas te la de el log de errores de tu servidor.

Comment: Si dices que en local funciona bien y en el servidor no, verifica si estás incluyendo archivos, los cuales existen en local, pero en el servidor no. Lo mismo podría ocurrir con respecto a la base de datos: puede que en local se conecte correctamente a la base de datos pero en el servidor no, porque la misma no esté configurada o porque las credenciales de conexión no son las mismas. Si logras leer el `error_log` sería de gran ayuda para resolver el problema.

Comment: Añadí este código PHP al principio de tu programa, de tal forma que tu servidor muestre los mensajes de error: **ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);**

Comment: Gracias Leandro...puse el codigo que me diste y este es el erro que me muestra:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.'...

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. El problema quedo resuelto, al cambiar la versión de  php que estaba ejecutando el servidor web donde tengo mi aplicativo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega esta función en tu archivo

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
?>
```

Comment: Si puede servir, pero no todas las personas son del mismo país.

Comment: ayudaría si pusieras el formato de las time zones